# how to pass value with bindActionCreators?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Until now I've been dealing with two kind of `mapDispatchToProps` :

One :

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    fetchgadata: bindActionCreators(fetchgadata, dispatch)
  };
}
```

Two :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onTimeChange: (e) => {dispatch (onSetTimeRange(e.target.value));},    
  };
};
```

What I would like to do is using `e.target.value` with `bindActionCreators`. So How should I refactor the first `mapDispatchToProps` above if I want to include `e.target.value` inside and pass this value to my `fetchgadata` action creator ?

I'm learning so I hope my question is clear. Please help me to improve it if not ! Thanks.

Comment: check this https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/168

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing the event args, pass in e.target.value. That value will be the first argument in the action creator. Component code should be:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
  this.props.onTimeChange(e.target.value);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand nothing of your answers. Can you give a little bit more details ? also what do you mean by "That value will be the first argument in the action creator" ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    bindActionCreators({ 
      fetchgadata: function(e) {
        dispatch(onSetTimeRange(e.target.value));
      }
    }, dispatch)
  };
}
```

If you want more function, you can simplify add to the bottom and keep chaining

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use bindActionCreators , you should write it like this :

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    fetchgadata: bindActionCreators((event) => fetchgadata(event.target.value), dispatch),
  };
};
```